# Intent is not passing on single click with loading firebase data

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-realtime-database

In my code, when user click on a button, it calls a function.In that function data has to loaded from firebase. On successful of loading, Intent will pass to another activity with some putExtra data.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("My_pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        choice = pref.getInt("language", 0);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               if(choice==1)
                {
                    firebase("param1","param2","English");
                }
                if(choice==2)
                {
                    firebase("param1","param2","hindi");
                }

            }
        });

 public void firebase(String files,String titles,String language)
    {

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(language);
        DatabaseReference myRef1=myRef.child(titles);
        DatabaseReference myRef2=myRef.child(files);
        myRef1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                language_title = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                t=1;

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        myRef2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                language_file= dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                f=1;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

            if(t==1&&f==1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), caf.class);
                i.putExtra("titles", language_title);
                i.putExtra("files", language_file);
                startActivity(i);
            }

    }
```

But in that case intent is only passing when I click twice.In single click Intent is not passing. where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any code that needs data from the database, needs to be *inside* the `onDataChange` method or be called from there.

See my answer here for a longer explanation: [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519).

Since you have two `onDataChange` methods, you'll need to make sure both have been called before starting the new activity. Using some simple flag variables to track state, you can do that with:

Declare two member fields:

```
boolean isTloaded, isFLoaded;
```

And then

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(language);
    DatabaseReference myRef1=myRef.child(titles);
    DatabaseReference myRef2=myRef.child(files);

    isTloaded = false;
    isFloaded = false;

    myRef1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            language_title = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            t=1;
            isTloaded = true;
            if (isTloaded && isFloaded) {
                startCafActivity();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
        }
    });
    myRef2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            language_file= dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            f=1;
            isFloaded = true;
            if (isTloaded && isFloaded) {
                startCafActivity();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
        }
    });
```

And then finally:

```
private void startCafActivity() {
    if(t==1&&f==1) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), caf.class);
        i.putExtra("titles", language_title);
        i.putExtra("files", language_file);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

It might be even simpler, but I had a hard time figuring out your application logic due to the variable names. Consider using more descriptive named than `t`, `f` and `caf` to make it easier for others (and your future self) to understand what each part of the code does in isolation.

Comment: It's working. Thank you FVP. you are always awsm and thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I want to do so. But I am new on this site. I don't have that much of reputation to do so.

Comment: Anyone who asks a question can accept an answer, it just takes some time before you can. :)

https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer